# AWS SAM and the changes in resource ARNs with each deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I see that one SAM deployment over another, that the previous resources are deleted, and new resources are created. Now, the new resources that are created are actually not the same resources, and have a different ARN than before.

This causes some problems that I am facing right now. Say that we have non SAM resources which require set for for the SAM resources.

Like for example, we have an SNS which is subscribed by our API gateway. Now after the deployment the ARN of the API gateway changes, and we'd require to subscribe again.

There are more problems like this that I am facing, but this is the gist of it.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I guess there are dedicated "subscription" or "integration" resource
So you can include these subscription or integration into SAM 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sns-subscription.html

Comment: @qkhanhpro Yeah I looked into that, but that didn't make any sense to me. Let's say you have a SNS. By this method, anyone can subscribe to the SNS without your approval. So I don't think this should work. Also this is the output of the SNS event, as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-sns.html), so I think this might not be it.

Comment: Well there is a comment in that resource "For a subscription to be created, the owner of the endpoint must confirm the subscription." ... But may be I'm wrong as I am not really afmiliar with SNS. Let's see if someone else have an idea

Comment: @qkhanpro "Owner of the endpoint" wouldn't that be the owner of the API gateway...? I thought it was to be the API owner who confirms the subscription. But the problem I see is the subscription creation itself. If the SNS owner doesn't create a subscription then there is nothing for the API owner to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ARN of the resource can remain same if the name of the resource is specified in the template. Since the name now remains the same, the ARN too will remain the same, even after multiple deployments.